# Laravel : how How to send Email using Cron job on Windows?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron

I want to do Laravel cron job on windows.For that I have done the following steps from the [Tutorial](http://laravel-bd.blogspot.com/2016/06/how-to-send-email-using-cron-job-in-laravel.html) But cron job doesn't work in my application.

First I have crated a command:

```
php artisan make:console SendEmails --command=emails:send
```

Then I have write the code handle() :

```
public function handle(Request $request)

    {

        $user=User::all();


            Mail::queue('send', ['user' => $user], function($m) use ($user)

                {

                    foreach ($user as $user) {

                        $m->to($user->email)->subject('Email Confirmation');

                    }                     

                });

    }
```

Then I have added the following line in command array:

```
Commands\SendEmails::class,
```

And added the following line on protected schedule function():

```
$schedule->command('SendEmails')

                 ->everyMinute();
```

So it's should send the email everyMinute. But nothing send.Added to say when i run the command, it's send email immediately for there's no problem of email sending.

```
php artisan emails:send
```

Comment: `cron` is not a Windows program. You can't use it with Windows. Tutorial you linked is oriented for *nix environment.

Comment: `foreach ($user as $user) {`? You can't call the child vars the same as the parent

Answer (score 1):

You have to [schedule a task](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx) in Windows with the command.

Comment: If you have done that before, can you please just give the instruction please ..Because I'm not clearer to the solution.